# How to get session variable on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have set session variable in my service implementation on LOG IN button click. And want to redirect on different page according to data returned and want to use different session variables on different pages .
but unable to use it . this code has written in login page from where i want to redirect.

```
$(function() {
    $("#loginButton").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "http://localhost:9090/login",
            data : {
                username : $("#user").val(),
                password : $("#pass").val()
            },
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data) {
                    var path="${pageContext.request.contextPath}";
                    /* alert(path); */
                    var user="<%=session.getAttribute("Username")%>"; 
                    $(location).attr("href",path.concat("/performance/performanceprofit.jsp"));
                }
                else {
                    $("#error").text("Invalid Username or Password");
                }
            }
        })
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#error").empty();
});
```

Comment: `var user` wont be what you expect as it will probably get assigned a value when your page loads, not when your AJAX success function is called.

Comment: @putvande  i think you are right . session sets variable after ajax call completion so might be the reason i have not been able to use it. thanx .